# how to use SharedPreferences for android and ios in one app in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am currently build an app that use `SharedPreferences` to save my data, but as I know, I have to use Shared preferences for Android and NSUserDefaults for iOS, is there a way or condition so that I can use both of them (Shared preferences and NSUserDefaults) inside my app... so my app can be used for android and iOS when saving the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package for storing app preference simple data into your app.

> Wraps NSUserDefaults (on iOS) and SharedPreferences (on Android), providing a persistent store for simple data. Data is persisted to disk asynchronously. Neither platform can guarantee that writes will be persisted to disk after returning and this plugin must not be used for storing critical data.

Storing:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('name', 'Bob');
```

Retrieving:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final name = prefs.getString('name');
```

You can store and retrieve int, string, bool, double, etc.
For more info, check out this [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/).

Comment: what I mean is how to use Shared preferences and NSUserDefaults in the same time, because as I know, Shared preferences is used for Android and NSUserDefaults for iOS

Comment: Yes, you can use this package for storing simple data permanently in both android and ios platforms. Please check out the documentation which I've added in my answer.

Comment: so when I use NSUserDefaults in my code, can I run my app correctly in android although that code is using NSUserDefaults for iOS ?

Comment: You don't need to use native SharedPreference(Android) or NSUserDefaults(iOS) for flutter projects. Using SharedPreference(Pub package) is enough for storing simple data in your app permanently.

Comment: Ask me if you're having any doubts. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if you liked it. @uyhaW

Comment: so to ensure that, is that true if I say like this: "I build an app so that my app can be used for both iOS and android, and I use SharedPreferences package for storing data, and this is also part of my code ```SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('name', 'Bob');```),...so after  I finish build my app and install my apk debug in android and iOS.. it will run well for both iOS and android and I just need to ignore NSUserDefaults"

Comment: is that true if I say like that?

Comment: Yeah, it'll work perfectly on both platforms. If my answer clears your doubts then kindly accept it.

Comment: Happy Coding.. @uyhaW